# How to upgrade from elementary OS Freya 0.3.1?

Tags: release-freya

I am currently running elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 and am looking for an upgrade.Which would be most suitable to upgrade too and how would I do this.I have seen some talking about clean installs,which version should I use and how would I do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, development is working towards elementaryOS 6 which should come out sometime this year, 2021.
At this time, elementaryOS 5.1 Hera, the latest release, is recommended.
You can grab the ISO from [elementary's website](https://elementary.io/) and follow their [installation instructions](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation) to perform a *clean* install.
This will overwrite all the data on your disk so first backup all your necessary data to the cloud, another computer, and/or an external drive.
Make sure to *test* your backup so you're certain all of your important data is accessible and valid.